# How to recompile ExtJs 5 theme with custom scss added

Tags: extjs, build, sass, themes, extjs5

I want to add this:

```
@include extjs-tab-panel-ui(
    $ui: 'navigation',
    $ui-tab-background-color: transparent,
    $ui-tab-background-color-over: #505050,
    $ui-tab-background-color-active: #303030,
    $ui-tab-background-gradient: 'none',
    $ui-tab-background-gradient-over: 'none',
    $ui-tab-background-gradient-active: 'none',
    $ui-tab-color: #acacac,
    $ui-tab-color-over: #c4c4c4,
    $ui-tab-color-active: #fff,
    $ui-tab-glyph-color: #acacac,
    $ui-tab-glyph-color-over: #c4c4c4,
    $ui-tab-glyph-color-active: #fff,
    $ui-tab-glyph-opacity: 1,
    $ui-tab-border-radius: 0,
    $ui-tab-border-width: 0,
    $ui-tab-inner-border-width: 0,
    $ui-tab-padding: 24px,
    $ui-tab-margin: 0,
    $ui-tab-font-size: 15px,
    $ui-tab-font-size-over: 15px,
    $ui-tab-font-size-active: 15px,
    $ui-tab-line-height: 19px,
    $ui-tab-font-weight: bold,
    $ui-tab-font-weight-over: bold,
    $ui-tab-font-weight-active: bold,
    $ui-tab-icon-width: 24px,
    $ui-tab-icon-height: 24px,
    $ui-bar-background-color: #404040,
    $ui-bar-background-gradient: 'none',
    $ui-bar-padding: 0,
    $ui-strip-height: 0
);
```

to ext-theme-crisp and then compile and get custom ext-all.css. How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found detailed answer/info about this topic here: http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/up-and-running/themes-introduction

It is very helpfull.

**DETAILS:**
Basicaly, i wanted to try this example locally: http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/examples/kitchensink/#side-navigation-tabs

So, these are things to do to accomplish what i asked:

First of all you have to generate workspace using [Sencha Cmd](http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download) . In workspace there is ext lib with themes and your apps + with your themes optionally. **-ext** option means that this command will download extjs inside your workspace, it's very helpful.

```
    sencha generate workspace -ext my-workspace
```

Then you have to go into your workspace and generate you application. (**-sdk ext** this means that extjs lib is in ext directory. ExtJs lib is always used when you build app or do other operations on you app)

```
    cd my-workspace
    sencha -sdk ext generate app ThemeDemoApp theme-demo-app
```

I wanted to add custom ui for my tabpanel. Let's create that tabpanel in proper directory:

```
    cd theme-demo-app 
    vim app/view/main/TabPanel.js
```

I use vim but you can do it with any text editor. Put this code into that file:

```
Ext.define('ThemeDemoApp.view.main.TabPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'customtabpanel',

    ui: 'navigation',
    tabPosition: 'left',
    tabRotation: 0,

    tabBar: {
        border: false
    },

    items: [{
        title: 'Tab 1',
        html: 'text content'
    }, {
        title: 'Tab 2',
        html: 'text content'
    }, {
        title: 'Tab 3',
        html: 'text content'
    }]
});
```

Now we have to define **ui:'navigation'** in css. For this we have to create **TabPanel.scss** file in same directory as class is relative to app (**view/main**) in **sass/src** directory:

```
mkdir sass/src/view
mkdir sass/src/view/main
vim sass/src/view/main/TabPanel.scss
```

And put saas script in that file using any text editor (i use vim):

```
@include extjs-tab-panel-ui(
    $ui: 'navigation',
    $ui-tab-background-color: transparent,
    $ui-tab-background-color-over: #505050,
    $ui-tab-background-color-active: #303030,
    $ui-tab-background-gradient: 'none',
    $ui-tab-background-gradient-over: 'none',
    $ui-tab-background-gradient-active: 'none',
    $ui-tab-color: #acacac,
    $ui-tab-color-over: #c4c4c4,
    $ui-tab-color-active: #fff,
    $ui-tab-glyph-color: #acacac,
    $ui-tab-glyph-color-over: #c4c4c4,
    $ui-tab-glyph-color-active: #fff,
    $ui-tab-glyph-opacity: 1,
    $ui-tab-border-radius: 0,
    $ui-tab-border-width: 0,
    $ui-tab-inner-border-width: 0,
    $ui-tab-padding: 24px,
    $ui-tab-margin: 0,
    $ui-tab-font-size: 15px,
    $ui-tab-font-size-over: 15px,
    $ui-tab-font-size-active: 15px,
    $ui-tab-line-height: 19px,
    $ui-tab-font-weight: bold,
    $ui-tab-font-weight-over: bold,
    $ui-tab-font-weight-active: bold,
    $ui-tab-icon-width: 24px,
    $ui-tab-icon-height: 24px,
    $ui-bar-background-color: #404040,
    $ui-bar-background-gradient: 'none',
    $ui-bar-padding: 0,
    $ui-strip-height: 0
);
```

Let's use our custom tabpanel instead of default tabpanel used in **app/view/main/Main.js** So, code of that file must look like this:

```
Ext.define('ThemeDemoApp.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    requires: ['ThemeDemoApp.view.main.TabPanel'],
    xtype: 'app-main',

    controller: 'main',
    viewModel: {
        type: 'main'
    },

    layout: {
        type: 'border'
    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        bind: {
            title: '{name}'
        },
        region: 'west',
        html: '<ul><li>This area is commonly used for navigation, for example, using a "tree" component.</li></ul>',
        width: 250,
        split: true,
        tbar: [{
            text: 'Button',
            handler: 'onClickButton'
        }]
    },{
        region: 'center',
        xtype: 'customtabpanel'
    }]
});
```

Now we have to build app. (It is important to put our new component in **requires** otherwise sencha cmd will ignore what we have done so far :) )

```
sencha app build
```

And run app locally:

```
sencha app watch
```

And finally open this and see result: [Demo App](http://1270.0.1:1841/theme-demo-app/)

Comment: The up and running link mentioned above is now part of the documentation at : http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/core_concepts/theming.html